# How to reduce amount of edge lines as in picture?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edges, faces

I am currently moddeling a house using a guide on youtube. Pretty much everything went allright untill I ended up questioning myself on this:

In the screenshot below you can clearly see there are a whole bunch of lines and edges, which are making the interface really messy and hard to work in:

[image]

Now what I basically want to achieve is the following:

[image]

Which will most likely be a lot easier to work in.

You might have noticed that the outer edges of the building aren't visible either, how can I fix these two "problems"?

*This might sound like a dumb question, but thank you all in advance for taking the time to help me out!*

Comment: I don't see anything "really messy" in the first picture. If you want to work with interface like in the second picture use preset orthographic views - `Numpad1`, `Numpad 3` and `Numpad7`.

Comment: You saved my day, thank you very much! I noticed you can use this to enter the building or leave the building aswell. But is it possible to fly through or something and put the camera on that location? @MrZak

Comment: You can use [Walk / Fly mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#walk-fly-mode) to navigate in 3D Viewport if that's what you want. For options look in the bottom of the 3D View header,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better workflow would be to use “Loop Cuts” to form the edges of your doors and windows. In “Edit Mode” place you cursor near an appropriate edge and press “CTRL” + “R” then right Mouse click to insert it then you can move it by moving the mouse. When satisfied “Right mouse click to lock it into place. Rinse and repeat for the other edges.

If you need to delete an edge loop press “X” then select “Edge Loop” from the drop down menu.

If you need to move an edge loop after the fact press “CTRL + “E” and select “Edge Slide” from the drop down menu. This will work for a section of an edge loop as long as it is bound by at least two vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will use this in the future. I did use the loop cuts allready though, only I did not know everything you explained. Thx for this!

Comment: I add an additional image for reference.